# create new certificate using private key

Tags: x509certificate2

I am trying to use a certificate from cert store to sign SAML request. Here what I am trying to do. (cert is the certificate from cert store)

```
RSACryptoServiceProvider tempRsaProvider = cert.PrivateKey as RSACryptoServiceProvider;
RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaProvider = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] privateKeyBlob = tempRsaProvider.ExportCspBlob(true);
rsaProvider.ImportCspBlob(privateKeyBlob);
SAMLMessageSignature.Generate(authnRequest, rsaProvider, cert, null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256", "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256");
```

This errors out when I try to Export in line tempRsaProvider.ExportCspBlob(true). The exportable property of the certificate is false (i.e., the certificate was imported without enabling exportable flag).

This works when I delete and import the same certificate by enabling exportable feature.

Here is my Question:
Is there a way to use the existing certificate's private key to generate a RSACryptoServiceProvider object (by creating a new temp certificate?) to be used in signing when the certificate was initially installed as not exportable?

I haven't found any meaningful information yet to do it through code. Any references/suggestions will help a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can't export non-exportable key. Instead, you need to use existing key provider instance to use the key.

Comment: Why don't you use `tempRsaProvider` in `SAMLMessageSignature.Generate`?

Comment: @pepo - using the tempRsaProvider doesn't work as the provider type of the certificate and the one expected in SAMLMessageSignature.generate are not the same. I am trying to create a new cert by updating the provider type and having issues.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't understand. But to your question. You don't need certificate to be exportable to use it for signing. If it was true then there would be no signatures made by certificate on a smartcard.